# GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-4.0.4.jar Does not contain AdManager?

Tags: android, admob

I've recently got my first Android App ready and (what testing has so far indicated as) bug free. Following this, I have tried to integrate ads into it but am encountering some issues when trying to set up my personal phone as a test device. Essentially, it appears that the jar resource file for AdMob, GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-4.0.4.jar, does not contain the object 'AdManager'. When reviewing the includes which are neccessary, I have determined that they are in 'com.admob...'. However, my resource file does not even contain this.

The jar file has been imported and is operating - I am able to set up AdViews and set AdRequests to be in test mode and successfully obtain test ads in the emulator, but I would like to set my phone to be a test device permanently, to prevent any possibility of AdMob thinking that there's some fraudulent stuff going on when I use my App myself.

Has anyone else experienced anything like this?

If not, is there a way I can set up my own device to permanently be a test device without using AdManager?

Thank you all in advance,
Andrew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i am not clear. You want you device to show real adds instead of the test add.If you are getting the adds in test mode then it is perfect. You just need to comment the AdManager line in the java file..

Comment: Thanks Soorya, I think I am just overly worried about them seeing my phone making ad requests. The ads work perfectly, but I'm unable to find a way to set my personal HTC to be a test phone. No worries though, and thanks for the answer.